# Can a capacitor have high series resistance and low Q and why?

Tags: capacitor, resistance, measurement, capacitance, esr

I measured with an LRC meter (Agilent 1731A) a capacitor at frequency \$1kHz\$, finding \$C=109.4 n F\$.

Then I tried to measure the resistance and quality factor of the capacitor: here is what I got.

Series mode @ \$f_0=1kHz\$ : \$R_C=95 \Omega\$ and \$Q=14.8\$.

As expected I have \$Q=\frac{1}{f_0 2 \pi C R_C}\$

The series resistance is very high and the quality factor very low.. What could be the reason for finding such values in a capacitor? Is it "common" to have high series resistances in capacitors?

Comment: is it - by any chance - a tantalum cap?

Comment: That would be an unusually high ESR for a ~100nF cap.  I suspect your measurement technique is off.  What kind of cap is it?  What does the datasheet say for ESR?

Comment: @JohnD LRC meter I used does not have a ESR mode, but it can measure quality factor \$Q\$ and I measured the series resistance like if \$C\$ was a resistor (so in series resistance mode on the meter). Is it incorrect to do so?

Comment: @Christian I do not know the type of capacitor unfortunately

Comment: @Sørën You measured the parallel resistance + series resistance. At 90 Ohm you either did something very wrong or your capacitor is very broken.